# Running an Eclipse RCP application from eclipse with Maven?

Tags: maven, maven-2, eclipse-rcp, m2e

I am new to Maven. We have an Eclipse RCP application that is mavenized. We do not use Tycho. It is Maven+m2e. It builds fine when doing the mvn clean install command. It writes out the manifest.mf to target/classes to each plugin, pulls the dependencies, copies dependencies to target/classes/lib and creates the plugins folder and all during build phase. But how do we run the application from eclipse using "Run as Eclipse Application"? It doesn't write out the manifest to {baseDir}/META-INFat this time.Nor does it copy dependencies to {baseDir}/lib folder. And it is not pulling any dependencies from local repo. Should I specifically use any maven plugins or use bind goals to different build phases while doing this? How is the classpath generated with Maven during Run as Application? Here is a code snippet used in our project that specifically generates manifest, copies dependencies e.t.c

The below code snippet "compiles" an Eclipse product by creating and/or staging all of the necessary plugins and other metadata files with the proper directory structure.

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
                <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                        <pluginExecutions>
                            <pluginExecution>
                                <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                    <groupId>
                                        com.cerner.engineering
                                    </groupId>
                                    <artifactId>
                                        cerner-eclipse-packaging-plugin
                                    </artifactId>
                                    <versionRange>
                                        [3.4,)
                                    </versionRange>
                                    <goals>
                                        <goal>compile-product</goal>
                                    </goals>
                                </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                                        <action>
                                    <ignore></ignore>
                                </action>
                            </pluginExecution>
                        </pluginExecutions>
                    </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

This is how we are copying dependencies to target/classes/lib folder of plugin. The generate-osgi-manifest goal runs during the "compile" phase.

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.cerner.engineering</groupId>
            <artifactId>cerner-osgi-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
                <classpath>., lib/markup-convert-3.1.jar,
                    src/main/resources/</classpath>
                <requiredExecutionEnvironment>JavaSE-1.6</requiredExecutionEnvironment>
                <exportPackages>
                    <enabled>false</enabled>
                </exportPackages>
                <localization>plugin</localization>
                <headers>
                    <header>
                        <name>Export-Package</name>
                        <values>
                            <value>
                                <name>the packages to be exported
                                    </name>
                            </value>
                        </values>
                    </header>

                    <header>
                        <name>Bundle-SymbolicName</name>
                        <values>
                            <value>
                                <name>bundle name</name>
                                <directives>
                                    <singleton>true</singleton>
                                </directives>
                            </value>
                        </values>
                    </header>
                    <header>
                        <name>Require-Bundle</name>
                        <values>
                            <value>
                                <name> required bundles</name>
                            </value>
                        </values>
                    </header>
                    <header>
                        <name>Bundle-Name</name>
                        <values>
                            <value>
                                <name>%Bundle-Name.0</name>
                            </value>
                        </values>
                    </header>
                    <header>
                        <name>Bundle-Vendor</name>
                        <values>
                            <value>
                                <name>%Bundle-Vendor.0</name>
                            </value>
                        </values>
                    </header>
                    <header>
                        <name>Import-Package</name>
                        <values>
                            <value>
                                <name>Imported packages</name>
                            </value>
                        </values>
                    </header>
                    <header>
                        <name>Eclipse-RegisterBuddy</name>
                        <values>
                            <value>
                                <name>Registered Bundle</name>
                            </value>
                        </values>
                    </header>
                </headers>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>generate-osgi-manifest</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
            <configuration>
                <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/classes/lib</outputDirectory>
                <overWriteReleases>true</overWriteReleases>
                <overWriteSnapshots>true</overWriteSnapshots>
                <stripVersion>false</stripVersion>
                <includeArtifactIds>markup-convert</includeArtifactIds>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>process-resources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

This all works fine when built from command line or using Maven build. And after the build when I run the executable it runs fine. But it doesn't work when I run as Eclipse Application. Or launch the application from the product file. Should I add any Maven plugins to do this? I did not understand how this works. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can't you just unpack the product and run that? Then you can start it with jvm settings enabling you to remote debug your eclipse product.

Comment: I am already using remote debug. But it is always nice to be able to run and debug from eclipse development environment itself.